# open android market

Tags: android

i have upload some apps in android market.now i want to  show or redirect users to my other apps.they can easily see and download other apps.please how to open other apps or how to redirect my app in application

if any sample code that is good for me

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent

Comment: You can also use the information in that link to send them to the Market page for the app itself. Something along the lines of: `"market://details?id=" + this.getClass().getPackageName()`. I did this in my app to encourage people to rate and comment.

Comment: oh nice I didn't even think about using getPackageName() I always hard coded it.